# Read 'status' of Windows program from Node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, winapi

I need to use Node.js to read a simple ON/OFF status of a Windows software as shown in the screenshot below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nbkO.png

I was thinking about reading the pixel color on the screen at that specific position (not sure how), writing the value into a file my Node folder and reading the file.

What would be the simplest way to do this or is there an even better way?

Comment: This looks like a measurement application, and I would be very surprised if it didn't provide a programming interface. Do some research.

Comment: I did, went through the manual and didnt find anything. It's a very old software (>10 years).

Comment: This is the software if anyone's wondering:http://www.princetonappliedresearch.com/download.asbx?AttributeFileId=aad2dd17-d8db-4585-b6bb-8d973c55a20a